# mutate_ column using a calculated column name in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following data.frame

```
qs <- structure(list(Question = c("This is a question", "This is a question"), 
Correct_Answer = c("D", "B"), 
Answer.A = c("This is an answer", "This is an answer"), 
Answer.B = c("This is an answer", "This is an answer"), 
Answer.C = c("This is an answer", "This is an answer"), 
Answer.D = c("This is an answer", "This is an answer"), 
Explanation = c("Just because!", "Just because!"), 
Response_A = c("", ""), 
Response_B = c("", ""), 
Response_C = c("", ""), 
Response_D = c("", "")), 
.Names = c("Question", "Correct_Answer", "Answer.A", "Answer.B",
           "Answer.C", "Answer.D", "Explanation", "Response_A", 
           "Response_B", "Response_C", "Response_D"), 
row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")
```

I want to set the `Response_X` value to match the `Explanation` for each question. For example in the first row, the `Correct_Answer` is D, so the `Response_D` should equal to the explanation, the other `Responses_` should remain blank.

I've tried the following:

```
library(dplyr)

qs %>% rowwise() %>% mutate_(.dots=setNames(paste(Explanation), 
                          paste0("Response_",Correct_Answer)))
```

It gives:

```
Error in paste0("Response_", Correct_Answer) : 
  object 'Correct_Answer' not found
```

I feel I should be using apply here, but not sure how.

Comment: I think the observed and actual answers should be the observations (rows) of the dataset, and the questions the variables, i.e. the columns should be called `Q1`, `Q2`, `Q3`, etc. `Explanation` would remain a variable and be repeated for each answer.

Comment: At the moment each row is an individual Question. And all the answers attached to that question only. Where it says Response_ that is the response the computer will give for any submitted answer. I want the explanation to go in the response given to the correct answer. Does that make more sense?

Comment: OK. I don't think you need many more columns which are mostly empty. Try instead a "tidy" data approach if this is possible. See answer below.

Comment: Problem is the format I use above is the format needed to import the data into another program. Even if I have a more refined data model, I still need to convert it with columns empty for some rows and not others

Comment: Fair enough. It's probably possible to "gather" your data to the tidy form, perform the operation and "spread" it back with `tidyr`. That might take me longer to figure out though.

Comment: Think I've worked out this gathering/spreading solution. See my edit below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `tidyverse` solution. You gather the data to a "tidy" form, mutate conditionally on `Correct_Answer`, and spread it back.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

qs %>% 
   gather(Resp, val, Response_A:Response_D, -Correct_Answer, -Explanation) %>% select(-val) %>% 
   mutate(Expl = if_else(paste("Response", Correct_Answer, sep="_") == Resp, Explanation, "")) %>%
   spread(Resp, Expl)
```

Hope that does the trick!

Answer (score 2):

One way is using a custom function which assigns the correct value in the correct column for that row

```
assignValue <- function(x) {
   qs[x, paste0("Response_", qs$Correct_Answer[x])] <<- qs$Explanation[x]
 }
```

and then call the function for every row using `sapply`

```
sapply(1:nrow(qs), function(x) assignValue(x))
```

Note, the use of `<<-` operator in the function. From the help page (`?"<<-"`)

> The operators <<- and ->> are normally only used in functions, and cause a search to made through parent environments for an existing definition of the variable being assigned. If such a variable is found (and its binding is not locked) then its value is redefined, otherwise assignment takes place in the global environment

Answer (score 1):

Using regular for loop you could do this:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(qs)){
    qs[i,paste('Response_',qs[i,'Correct_Answer'], sep = '')]=qs[i,'Explanation']
}
```

Im still trying to figure out how to update the col values using sapply.

```
sapply(1:nrow(qs), function(i) qs[paste('Response_',qs[i,'Correct_Answer'], sep = '')]=qs[i,'Explanation'])
```

Comment: I have not used global assignment as you have used in your answer. Also  i think mine is more simple solution.